# Call WebService using HTTPWebRequest object

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

i want to consuming a web service with  HTTPWebRequest object the web service may be written using java.(doon't want to consume adding web reference)

Answer (score 5):

Marcin provides a sample in his blog: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201021135807/http://geekswithblogs.net/marcel/archive/2007/03/26/109886.aspx) .

Though it's consuming a .net based web service, but it doesn't make difference from the consumer's point of view.

The basic idea is you need to compose a soap request message and send it to server properly.